# vlc.playlist.loop automation

Tags: lua, vlc

Basically I have this .lua code in my vlc extension, now I am having problems in setting the VLC repeat automatically to loop all in a playlist.
I have tried setting it into "all", 0, 1, 2, true, "TRUE" but it does just not set the playlist's loop value into "all".

I also cannot get the playlist loop value. I tried object.playlist().loop, vlc.playlist.loop.

I read the [VLC's Lua Script and Extensions page](https://www.videolan.org/developers/vlc/share/lua/README.txt) but I still cannot get what is supposed to be that

```
    <status>
```

value or any of its acceptable strings.

```
function trigger()
    vlc.playlist.stop()
    vlc.playlist.sort("random")
    vlc.playlist.goto(0)
    --vlc.playlist.repeat_(<status>)
    --vlc.playlist.loop(<status>)
    vlc.playlist.play()
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it, thanks to Vyacheslav and Piglet

this would now set the vlc playlist loop to loop all, but I cannot print or vlc.msg.info the value of playlist.loop though. But it works in the end.

```
function trigger()
    vlc.playlist.stop()
    vlc.playlist.sort("random")
    vlc.playlist.goto(0)
    playlist = vlc.object.playlist();
    if vlc.var.get(playlist,"loop") == false then vlc.playlist.loop() end
    vlc.playlist.play()
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried it but following the documentations logic status should be either `nil`, `true` or `false`. If `nil` (or no argument) it will toggle the current state. `true` will enable, `false` disable loop or repeat.

Not sure why you expect loop to be "all".

Did you remove the -- in front of the respective line?
I assume setting both doesn't make sense. And they will toggle each other internally?

Comment: Yes if course I did remove the -- that would make it a comment in the code but boolean values does not seem to work on the function.

Answer (score 0):

In common case, if you do not know how it properly works, it is possible to search such code in github.com.
In your case, you can use this:

https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=vlc.playlist.loop+language%3ALua&type=Code&ref=searchresults

As you can see,

you can use such code:

```
elseif command == "pl_loop" then
  vlc.playlist.loop()
elseif command == "pl_repeat" then
  vlc.playlist.repeat_()
```

or

```
 elseif c == 'loop' then
      if vlc.playlist.loop(v) then
        vlc.playlist.repeat_('off')
      end
    elseif c == 'repeat' then
      if vlc.playlist.repeat_(v) then
        vlc.playlist.loop('off')
      end
```

Comment: TIL. Thanks for the github advice, I would be searching for a similar code now and try to fix and resolve this problem if I could.